# How can I apply weights in Eigen unsupported levenberg marquardt implementation?

Tags: eigen3

I am using Eigen's levenberg marquardt algorithm to fit a surface, but there is a lot of noise in the data, so I need to filter out the noise by iterative weighting.
But I don't know where this weight should be added?
you know, in my LevenbergMarquardt functor, I must fill fvec with:

for(i...)
fvec(i) = f_i(x)

But in the actual problem, each observation has a different weight, I would like to get the weights from the residuals of the original fit and attempt a refitting via  levenberg marquardt using the weights.
so where should I add the weight?
Can you help me with an example? 
Thanks.

Comment: Put the square-root of the weights within the `f_i`.

Comment: Do you mean this?
For example, the function is：
z = a*x^2 + b*y^3
Where a, b are the parameters to be fitted, x and y, z are observations,
Then I have 3 sets of observations (2,1,7), (3,1,19), (4,1,34), corresponding to x, y, z respectively.
Then should I fill in this way?

fev(0) = (a*(2)^2 + b*(1)^3 - 7) * sqrt(weight(0)); 
fev(1) = (a*(3)^2 + b*(1)^3 - 19) * sqrt(weight(1)); 
fev(2) = (a*(4)^2 + b*(1)^3 - 34) * sqrt(weight(2)); 

I feel that this is not right.

Comment: Yes that's it. Recall that in your case, the weighted least-squares objective function is `sum_i w_i * ||g(x_i) - y_i||^2` for the model `g`, and observation couples `(x_i,y_i)`. Also let me add that for linear models as your `z = ax^2 + by^3` example no need to use a sophisticated non-linear solver.